# ASP.NET SQL - Pool - timeout

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, timeout, connection, pool

I've a problem with Asp.net and SQL.
I have many timeout errors from connection pool.

All connections are used within `using` block so they are correctly closed.
In the `connectionSting` I have : `Pooling=true;Max Pool Size=250`
System is Windows 2008 server, SQL Server 2008 , Asp.net

In application error log:

```
Event Id 1309
source : ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0
```

Or

```
Event Id 9
source : Active Server Pages
```

Do you have any suggestions what I should do?

Comment: Timing out in the sense that you can't get a new connection?

Comment: Can you post a typical section of code so we can see how you're doing the `open` and what you're doing with the connection?

Answer (score 0):

Give Timeout in web.config with connection string.
It works for me.